# Trying to load to a list of lists from a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to load from a list of dictionary items to a list of list in Python 2.7.  The data currently looks like 20 lines of the following:

```
[{'professional:xp': '100', 'personal:power': 'fly', 'personal:hero': 'yes', 'custom:color': 'black', 'professional:name': 'batman'}, {'professional:xp': '86', 'personal:power': 'think', 'personal:hero': 'no', 'custom:color': 'grey', 'professional:name': 'gandalf'}, ...]
```

I want to do something like this:

```
[[100, 'fly', 'yes', 'black', 'batman'][86, 'think', 'no', 'grey', 'gandalf']...]
```

I tried a lot of different ways to loop but I cannot get a result.

```
i = -1
j = -1
scanList = []
joinList = [[]]

for item in scanList:
    i = i+1
    for k, v in item.iteritems():
        j= j+1
        joinList[i][j].append(v)
```

I get the idea of loading the list via the nested loop (upfront I don't know if my i and j is in right place but I can work on that).  I just keep getting out of index errors and I don't know if I should be initialize the list of lists before?

Comment: use a list comprehension

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now's a good time to learn about *list comprehensions*. Note also that `[dict].values()` conveniently returns the list of values in a dictionary.

```
joinList = [d.values() for d in scanList]
```

---

Beware that in Python 3.x `values()` returns a *view object*, which must be  explicitly converted to a list:

```
# Python 3.x version
joinList = [list(d.values()) for d in scanList]
```

Comment: Wow - you made it look so easy.  Once I'm finished work on this I am going right to learn more about list comprehensions.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can get the values of a dictionary with the [`values` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values). Now you have to iterate over your dictionaries and call values on them:

```
[d.values() for d in scan_list]
```

Comment: This is broken. `values()` doesn't return a list. I suggested an edit.

Comment: @alec935 OP is using Python 2.7, in which it does. You are probably using 3.x.

Comment: Ah, my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code:

```
for item in scanList:
    list = []
    for key, value in item.iteritems():
        list.append(value)
    joinlist.append(list)
```

Comment: this is inefficient

Answer (score 1):

```
data=[{'professional:xp': '100', 'personal:power': 'fly', 'personal:hero': 'yes', 'custom:color': 'black', 'professional:name': 'batman'}, {'professional:xp': '86', 'personal:power': 'think', 'personal:hero': 'no', 'custom:color': 'grey', 'professional:name': 'gandalf'}]

new_data=[list(j.values()) for j in data]
print(new_data)
```

output

```
[['yes', 'black', 'batman', 'fly', '100'], ['no', 'grey', 'gandalf', 'think', '86']]
```